# Change stroke width of a svg image with click function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to increase the stroke width of a svg image by 0.5 when the user clicks on a button. I have the click function already, but not sure how to get the function to work to increase the stroke width.

```
function pipeScaleFactorPlus(){
    $(".pipe").style("stroke-width", "+=0.5");

  drawMapPipes();    
}
```

.pipe is the svg class and the drawMapPipes(); is called to redraw the svg image.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? I.e. something we can run, even if it's broken.

Comment: What else do you need, like the click function as well? It's hard for me to create an example on codepen.io or something bc I'm pulling the svg from a db to create pipelines on a map.

Comment: Your example does not need to replicate the db thing it only needs to have  a pre-created object whose stroke width you're trying to adjust.

Comment: Also, jQuery has no `style()` function. Are you using some other plugin that adds that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. I was trying to make it more complicated then it had to be. I just created a new variables and set stroke widths to begin with and then added the function within the click function.

```
    $("#increasePipe").click(function(){
      map.pipeSize += 0.25;
        if (map.pipeSize > map.pipeSizeMax){
            map.pipeSize = map.pipeSizeMax;
        }
      map.svg.selectAll(".pipe").style("stroke-width", map.pipeSize);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using normal jQuery only.  Here is how you can adjust the stroke width.

Note that we have to do a little extra to modify some SVG properties because some have names that differ from the style property names.

For example, the attribute is named `stroke-width`, but the `style` property is `strokeWidth`.

```js
$("button").click(function(evt) {
  var myLine = $("line");
  // Get the current stroke-width.
  // Try getting it from the style object first. Otherwise get it direct
  // from the attribute value.
  // We use parseInt() to strip off any units ("20px" -> 20)
  var currentWidth = parseInt(myLine.css("strokeWidth") || myLine.attr("stroke-width"), 10);
  // Update the style property "strokeWidth".
  // Note that the property has a different spelling to the attribute.
  myLine.css("strokeWidth", 30 - currentWidth);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
  <line y1="75" x2="300" y2="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>

<button>Click me</button>
```